# WSO2 ESB > Manage endpoint text responses from proxy (Unexpected character 'some_character' code 45 in prolog expected '<')

Tags: text, proxy, wso2, response, apache-axis

I’m making a soap call to an endpoint service through ESB6.1.1 from SOAPUI

```
PROXY CONFIGURATION
 ((( I bloted out some information with xxxx )))

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="xxxxWsV2_Based_Proxy" startOnLoad="true" statistics="disable" trace="enable" transports="http,https">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <property name="EXPECT-100" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <log level="full"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <endpoint>
            <wsdl port="xxxxWsV2Port" service="xxxxxWsV2Service" uri="file:/var/www/html/xxxxWsV2.wsdl"/>
        </endpoint>
    </target>
    <description/>
</proxy>
```

SOAPUI receives a correct response when the endpoint service returns a ‘SOAP response’.

But i have other soap call that is returning the next non-soap formatted response:

```
NON-SOAP ENDPOINT RESPONSE
--urn:uuid:ax7xx36-98xx9-4ex1-bxxc-ax1xxxxx8bxc
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: <urn:uuid:3xcxxx4b-x9ea-xxf6-81c3-8a8xxxxe6bx7>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://xxxx.es/xxxx/ws/xxxxws_v2/1.0/infoEnvioV2">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<resultadoInfoEnvioV2>
<ns1:identificador>xa3x2xxxxx8xx7</ns1:identificador>
</resultadoInfoEnvioV2>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

--urn:uuid:a07xxx6-9xxx9-4xxa1-xx9c-a91dxxbcc
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <urn:uuid:69xxx17b-x96c-xx3e-9x78-721dxxxxxxa23>
http://xx.x.x.xxx/Texto_de_prueba.txt
--urn:uuid:a07xxx6-9xxx9-4ea1-bxxc-a9xxx0c8bcc—
```

The problem is that wso2-esb doesn’t return the response to SOAPUI because this ESB error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-12-21 17:15:38,305] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils} -  Error while building Passthrough stream {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils}
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '-' (code 45) in prolog; expected '<'
```

I'm only interested in reading last SOAP-ENV response from SOAPUI.

For getting the solution. I would like to TRANSFORM ‘ONLY’ THE PROXY RESPONSE to a format that SOAPUI can read.

For solving the problem. I added the property messageBuilder to the proxy’s out-sequence configuration:

```
NEW OUT-SEQUENCE PROXY CONFIGURATION
        <outSequence>
            <builder>
                <messageBuilder class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder" contentType="text/xml" formatterClass="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
            </builder>
            <log level="full"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
```

Note: When i added the last property messageBuilder. WSO2 editor added itself this new properties:

```
<outSequence>
    <builder>
        <messageBuilder class="org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder" contentType="application/xml" formatterClass="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter"/>
        <messageBuilder class="org.apache.axis2.builder.MIMEBuilder" contentType="multipart/related"/>
        <messageBuilder class="org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder" contentType="application/soap+xml" formatterClass="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
        <messageBuilder class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBuilder" contentType="application/json" formatterClass="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter"/>
        <messageBuilder class="org.apache.axis2.builder.MTOMBuilder" contentType="application/xop+xml"/>
        <messageBuilder class="org.apache.axis2.builder.XFormURLEncodedBuilder" contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" formatterClass="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.XFormURLEncodedFormatter"/>
    </builder>
    <log level="full"/>
    <send/>
</outSequence>
```

But unfortunately i don’t get any response in SOAPUI :(

After I make other tests adding the next properties in outsequence. But with no effect:

```
<property name="ContentType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
<property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
```

Note: I have used always the axis2.xml default file.

¿ Do you know which property should i use in my proxy configuration for managing this kind of text responses?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please take in consideration that i receive at the end of the response message this ==>

Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary